# replace characters according to positions in an loop

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm busy with an hangman application, and I've come to the point where I now have to display the secret word... Now I'm thinking of creating two Strings the original that retrieves an random word from a text file and the secret word that hides... Problem is I don't know how to hide an word in '-'

So i've created the following two strings

```
String original = readWord();
String secret = new String(new char[original.length()]).replace('\0', '-');
```

Now my idea is to find the position of the char in the original string and then replace the '-' with that char in the secret String

Now the problem is when my original word is for example "elephant", so I found an loop that finds the position of the char searched

```
String s = "elephant";
int pos = s.indexOf('e');
while (pos > -1) {
System.out.println(pos);
pos = s.indexOf('e', pos + 1);
```

now this loop returns

```
0
2
```

My Question is how do I use this loop to replace the '-' in the secret string whether there is more than 1 position returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `String` is immutable, you could use `StringBuilder` to build a new string:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(secret);
for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
    if (original.charAt(i) == guessLetter) {
        builder.setCharAt(i, guessLetter);
    }
}
secret = builder.toString();
```

You would use builder.toString() as your masked word until you picked a new word. When you get a new word you would reset the masked word to `'-------'` etc.

Comment: Okay but my original String retrieves an random word from an text file and what happens if the String changes to an word that has more than two "e"'s in different positions. I only used he word elephant and the positions as an example

Comment: You would reset your masked/secret word upon selecting a new word. See my update above.

Comment: I've tried your code above, and looks like I get an error everytime I press a button representing a letter in the word

Comment: I don't have any view to the rest of your code but this code works for me. guessLetter is a char type.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

String Str = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");

// all occurrence of 'o' is replaced with 'T'

System.out.println(Str.replace('o', 'T'));